# Get Excel Window back to Foreground

Tags: excel, outlook, office-2007, vba

I searched the Internet from top to the root, but I couldn't find a solution. In my Excel Workbook I want to import Contacts from Outlook. This works fine without any problems. I get the GAL to the foreground by using `Outlook.ActiveWindow.Activate` and I minimize Outlook by using `Outlook.Explorers.Item(1).WindowState = olMinimized`. I know this is not really a very clean solution, but everything works fine unless there are no other Outlook Windows opened.

Now to my problem: 
When the user has more than one opened Outlook Window (e.g. a new mail dialog, etc.) I can't bring my Excel Application back to Foreground. The import of contacts still works fine. The GAL comes to Foreground by clicking a Button. 
I tried the following code snippets, but they don't really work.

```
   Dim AppTitle As String
   AppTitle = Application.Caption
   '
   'some code
   '
   AppActivate AppTitle
```

Another attempt was this function in a module

```
   Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
```

calling it in my Button Function

```
   Dim AppXL As Object
   Set AppXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   '
   'some code
   '
   SetForegroundWindow AppXL.hWnd
```

I also tried to use this code snippet

```
   Excel.Application.Visible = True
   Excel.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate
```

Nothing helped. The only thing happened was the blinking Excel Icon in the taskbar. I hope you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this code is in your Excel workbook, it would just be:

```
   SetForegroundWindow Application.hWnd
```

rather than creating a new application instance.

Comment: That didn't help me. Still the same behavior. :/

Comment: I suggest you clarify some things such as: where is the code, what exactly did you mean by "I tried the following code snippets, but they don't really work.", and what, if anything, did happen when you tried this code?

Comment: The code is in a function of a Sheet under "Microsoft Excel Objects" of the Excel VBA-Editor. The code snippets were attempts trying to solve the problem. I found them in various forums. I didn't use them all at the same time. I experimented with them to try out what might work and like I said the only thing happened was a blinking Excel-Icon in my taskbar. When I tried to use your suggestion, nothing happened.

Comment: I too have this issue!  Was there a solution ever found to this?!?